# JPA Specification with an Expression

Tags: spring, jpa

I have a JPA Specification that I built with this syntax

```
newSpec = (root, query, cb) -> {        
    return cb.equal(root.get("livelloApprovazione"), root.join( "utentiInteressati").get("livello"));
};
```

that correctly maps to the native SQL I aspected:

```
select .... 
from documento documento0_ 
inner join documento_utenti utentiinte1_ 
    on documento0_.id_documento=utentiinte1_.id_documento 
where documento0_.livello_approvazione=utentiinte1_.livello
```

what I need is to add a **+1 expression** to the left side of the condition

```
select .... 
    ....
where documento0_.livello_approvazione + 1 = utentiinte1_.livello
```

with the additional expression + 1 on one side of the condition.

Is it possibile implement such a where condition as JPA Specification Predicate? If so How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    newSpec = (root, query, cb) -> 
            cb.equal(
                    cb.sum(root.get("livelloApprovazione"), 1), 
                    root.join( "utentiInteressati").get("livello")
            );
```

Comment: Thanks for answer it wotks

Comment: May be useful for you to explore. I was checking the signature of cb.equal in Intellij. It was taking 2 expressions as params. And Then I checked what are the implementations of `Expression` interface and one of them was `BinaryArithmeticExpression`